# Increase combobox size while the code is running

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to add new components in a JavaFX combo box while the code is running. For example I noticed that I cannot do something like this:

```
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

ComboBox<Text> combobox = new ComboBox<Text>();

combobox.getItems().setAll(new Text("Test 1"));
combobox.getItems().setAll(new Text("Test 2"));
```

New label overrides the old one. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: need to add new item to the combo box? and it should not be known to the user unless he/she click on the combo box drop down? am i rite?

Comment: Yes, the combo box will hold progressbars but this is not important. THe problem is how I can add/ remove components from the combobox?

Comment: The variable `combobox` is of which class exactly? Okay, assuming `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox`...

Comment: yes javafx.scene.control.ComboBox

Answer (score 3):

You can use add() of the oberservable list

as,

```
ComboBox<Text> combobox = new ComboBox<Text>();
combobox.getItems().add(<your new item>);
```

**or**

```
 combobox.getItems.add(combobox.getItems().size(), <your new item>);
```

To delete a item from combo box you have get the object and use

```
combo.getItems().remove(object)
```

Tried with sample. Please have a look,

```
   import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author JayaPrasad
 * 
 */
public class JavaFxSwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new String("test"), new String("name"));

        ObservableList<Text> textData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Text("item1"), new Text("item2"));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
        combo.setItems(data);

        final ComboBox<Text> comboText = new ComboBox<Text>();
        comboText.setItems(textData);

        Button btn = new Button("add");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                combo.getItems().add(combo.getItems().size(),
                        new String("new item"));
                comboText.getItems().add(comboText.getItems().size(),
                        new Text("item 3"));
            }
        });

        final HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setSpacing(20);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 40));
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(combo, comboText, btn);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);

                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

                frame.add(jfxPanel);

                frame.setSize(400, 100);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I tested this and I get out of bounds exception.

Comment: combobox.getItems().add(<your new item>); this one throws out of bound? Then can you post your code where you add data to combo? Also post your data (obervablelist) of combo

Comment: In the second option, getItems should be getItems() and size should be size(), but given those changes I can't see how either option could possibly throw an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: One additional question related to this post. How I can delete a specific object which is inserted into the Combobox?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you have get the object and use combo.getItems().remove(object) to delete a item from combo box.